# adjust x-axis labels flot js

Tags: javascript, jquery, graph, flot, chap-links-library

Is there any way to limit the number of x axis values that will be displayed given that there are many points to be displayed on the graph? Otherwise,the x-axis labels overlap if you don't zoom. For example, please see the fiddle I've created http://jsfiddle.net/ggggg/jx3q8uoy/10/
`enter code here`. You can zoom in and out with the mouse wheel. If you click on update I reload new data on the graph but since there are many points for the size of the graph the x-axis values get mixed with each other which is not good. One cannot make a difference which is which unless they zoom. Is there any way to limit the number of x-axis labels to be shown to just a few so that they don't get mixed in such a way when the point amount is big and if you zoom in then you will be able to see the specific x-axis labels? For example, please have a look at the vis.js graph here http://visjs.org/examples/graph2d/03_groups.html. See when you zoom in or zoom out with the mouse wheel the x-axis labels get rescaled and many of them get hidden and if you zoom in they are shown. I need something like for flot.js

Thanks

Comment: Your fiddle looks great, but it's very hard to read this block-description.

Comment: What's not clear please?

Comment: I'm confused.  First, you are setting your xaxis for `mode: "time"`, but your x-values are **not** time values.  Second, you are explicitly setting the ticks with `plot.getOptions().xaxes[0].ticks = ticks;`, flot will not do any auto-ticking when you set this value.  So, you have some choices to make, are you really working with time or not?  If not, do you want to work with categories that look like dates?  Do you want flot to auto-tick or do you want to roll your own algorithm to intelligently tick?

Comment: Mark, you are right, I am not really familiar with flot.js (I've started playing with it since yesterday). I don't care whether the dates are deemed as categories as long as the graph behaves in the way I want, namely it doesn't overlap the x-axis labels when there are many points.  All my x-axis which I am going to update will be dates. The only thing I care is to be able to zoom in and out and the graph should intelligently readjust the x-axis labels so that they don't get mixed. Do you now how I can do that? 10x

Comment: Initially I've just passed some data to load something but in reality I will update the graph via ajax on a click button and the x-axis ticks I will be passing will be dates that's why I've set up the mode to "time".

Comment: If you use real datetimes and let flot decide your ticks, I'm not sure this is an issue anymore: http://jsfiddle.net/jx3q8uoy/12/

Comment: Mark. Thanks for your reply. But the thing is that I would like to dynamically update the plot with new data and new sticks on an update click and in the same time retain the flot tick calculator of the x-axis labels? Can I do that?

Comment: So my question is if the graph is already drawn and I pass different data via ajax then will the same functionality such as auto-ticking be preserved?

Comment: Yes.  Just call `plot.setupGrid(); plot.draw();` and flot will re-auto tick.

Comment: thanks. So just out of curiosity, if you manually assign new ticks after you've already drawn the graph why does the auto-tick not work? Is it a bug?

Comment: And also, on the fiddle you've sent me, I see that for sin and cos arrays, the first parameter is a timestamp so that flot can read it? Is that seconds or milliseconds timestamp? And if I have a string date how can I convert that to the proper timestamp?

Comment: Yes, milliseconds, `(new Date(yourDateString)).getTime()`, see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) for more info.